# Displaying values on screen, but not in alert box

Tags: react-native, alert, fetch

```
 _onPressButtonPOST(){
        fetch("url", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
            body: JSON.stringify({"entryDate":"3/2/2017 2:00 AM","dia":"808","mobileType":"ANDROID","userName":"menutest"})})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            Alert.alert(
                "Blood pressure data",
                "Blood pressure data - " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
            })
        .done();
    }

    _onPressButtonGET(){
        fetch("url", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
            body: JSON.stringify({"mobileType":"ANDROID","userName":"menutest"})})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            Alert.alert(
                "Blood pressure data",
                "Blood pressure data - " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
    })
        .done();
    }



    render(){
        return(
            <View>


          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST} >
                    <Text>Add</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonGET} >
                    <Text>show</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>


            </View>
            );
    }
```

I am able to store values to the database and fetch them back but i am displaying those values in alert box but i want to display on screen, how to edit my code to display entryDate and dia on screen, whenever i click on show button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `state` -

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    data: ''
  };
}

_onPressButtonGET = () => {
  ....
  .then((responseData) => {
    this.setState({
      data: JSON.stringify(responseData)
    })
  })
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      .....
      .....
      <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: getting error like "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this2.setState({data:responseData}))

Comment: change `_onPressButtonGET(){` to `_onPressButtonGET = () => {`. Fat arrow function automatically binds `this`.

Comment: this is not working, by clicking on show nothing is happening.

Comment: <Text>{this.state.data}</Text> it is displaying the same line, not the data

Comment: I think you have `<Text>this.state.data</Text>`. Change it to `<Text>{this.state.data}</Text>`

Comment: changed now it is showing like "Objects are not valid as a React child (found : object with keys {....}). if u meant to reander collection of children , use an array instead or wrap the objects using reactFragment(object) from the react add-ons check the render method of text "

Comment: `this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(responseData) })`

Comment: thank you so much its working. but if i want to print only entryDate then?

Comment: this.setState({ data: responseData.entryDate })